# If my web application can't unmarshal client-supplied JSON, should I return 400 or 500?

Tags: json, http, http-status-codes

I'm trying to use HTTP response codes properly but I'm a bit confused by which to return in this situation:

The body of a POST request from the client should contain a JSON representation of an object in my application. Assuming the body is non-empty and the content is JSON data, if `json.Unmarshal` returns an error (I'm programming in Go, but not that it matters), does that warrant `400 Bad Request` or `500 Internal Server Error`?

On one hand if it doesn't decode the data because the format is wrong, that's a bad request, but on the other hand it's a function returning an error on the server that means the operation can't proceed so it's an internal server error. In essence it's a 500 caused by a 400. So which should I be returning?

Comment: If the data sent to you is bad, how does that equate to a server error?

Comment: Because I don't know ahead of time whether the error is returned because the format was bad or because there was some other problem server-side.

Comment: And so you'll have to return the appropriate error in each case.  You can't define before your call which error you should return.  Or maybe I have completely missed your point as it seems you last paragraph defines what you should return and when you should return it.